# Accessing the index of object

Tags: python-3.x

We can access the value of a certain index in a list like so:

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
print letters[1]
```

The code above will print the letter 'b', because it is in the index 1 of the list, letter. So in this way, we can access a certain object in a list.

Now, if we assume that `letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`, what code should we type to access the index of a certain object (assume it is the letter, 'c') in the list, `letters`?

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`, the following will return the index of `c` in `letters`:

```
>>> letters.index('c')
2
```

If the value is not in the list, it will raise an error instead:

```
>>> letters.index('k')
valueError: 'k' is not in list
```

Comment: Also note that `index` will only find the first occurrence of the requested object .